# Out of Order retirement of Store instruction

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

Suppose we have two instructions
Store A
Store B
and these two map to two different cache lines in the Cache.
Would an out-of-order retirement of Store (Store B over A) help in anyway consider a write back write allocate policy in the cache?
Assuming that there are no exceptions/ interrupts, no structural, control, data dependency or memory dependency, no cache conflict between the two instructions.

Comment: The reason why stores and loads need to retire in order is to comply with the sequential consistency model, which means, to a programmer at any given point of time, the memory should look as if the instructions before the current instructions are over and the younger have not been executed.
That said, the relaxed consistency models are not uncommon. Moreover, why do you want to reorder retirement? The reason you have in order retirement is to make sure that you can go back if precise interrupt hits.

Comment: Architectures that give precise exceptions can't *retire* any instructions out-of-order, only execute.  ([This paper about kilo-instruction processors talks about the issue, and alternatives to the traditional ROB with in-order retirement](http://personals.ac.upc.edu/fcazorla/articles/fcazorla_ieeemicro_kilo_2005.pdf).  e.g. checkpoint architectural state only at certain instructions.).  @Rgarg: I think you're mixed up: On a relaxed memory order architecture like ARM, a single thread still sees its *own* memory operations happen in program order.  So it doesn't have to fence its own stores!

Comment: You might want to execute out of order and that makes sense when address computation of B can happen before address computation of A.

Comment: @PeterCordes, So, you mean to say, even in relaxed memory order architectures, the loads and stores appear in order in the memory? Then what is the difference? Thanks.

Comment: @Rgarg: A single thread always observes it's *own* actions to happen in program order; otherwise it would be nearly impossible to program.  You'd need a memory barrier instruction between every store / reload.  [Strong vs. Relaxed](http://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/) refers to what other threads can see.  Relaxed memory models mean less coherency traffic when processes / threads are running that don't use memory barriers to make sure they see each other's actions.  Read Jeff Preshing's blog posts, they're very excellent.

Comment: @Rgarg: a thread always "sees" it's own instructions to happen in program order, but it does not mean instructions should execute in order. The out of order pipeline has to guarantee that instructions "seem" to happen to in order.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a relaxed consistency model and no fence between the two stores, then the very short answer is stores can "execute" out of order, and that might help performance.  Stores are usually written to a write queue (or store queue) before getting written to the cache. The write queue can be physically implemented as a queue, CAM, banked queue, etc. Assuming that the bank in the write queue that A is supposed to be written to is full, then the processor might be able to write B to another bank before writing A. Another example is when address of B is computed well before address of A. Note that the processor should always be able to reverse this action (i.e., writing to write queue and cache), if needed (e.g., when precise exception happens). But I guess this is hard to reverse, so I don't think this is ever done in practice.

Having said that, note that every instruction (load, store, ALU operation, etc.) is committed (retired) in order, but it does not mean that instructions should be executed in order.

Comment: The question says "retire".  You might want to add a note that the interesting question is whether stores can *execute* out of order, and that's what you're answering.  Stores do execute out of order in real life on real hardware.  Or at least become globally visible out of order, which isn't necessarily the same thing.  On x86, you can [see them appear out of order with loads](http://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/).  Probably a similar experiment with weakly-ordered NT stores could demonstrate store reordering.

Comment: Edited to clarify things.
Please point me to a paper or technical note saying in practice stores are executed out of order "with respect to stores" (I don't mean loads) in real hardware. I am not saying it does not exist, I am not aware of any.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any references to point you towards.  My reasoning for making such a strong statement was that memory ordering bugs in software are a real thing.  If stores became globally visible in-order on actual implementations of weakly-ordered architectures that don't guarantee that, I don't think there would be such a fuss about getting the fencing correct.  I don't think it's just StoreLoad reordering that's to blame for the kinds of bugs Linus Torvalds says people always introduce when they try to invent their own locking mechanism.

Comment: @PeterCordes, memory ordering bugs don't necessarily indicate stores are executed out of order. They're usually much more elusive and include multiple cores / threads where the memory operations may be observed in different global order even when the local order per thread is kept.

Comment: @Leeor: ok that's fair, usually people manage to think through any necessary barriers for threads to order the global visibility of their own stores.  And good point that one thread can observe a different global total order than another.  But surely we would have heard about it if StoreStore barriers were always completely unnecessary in practice on real hardware?

Comment: @PeterCordes, well, one reason they're necessary is to drain store buffers. TSO is not SC, therefor local stores may be reordered globally with other stores - a store fence may help guarantee they're finished in some cases (though only locally, you still need to order it somehow). Then there's also the weaker mem types or streaming writes that may reorder and require protection at some sync point.

Comment: @Leeor - I like to use [the table about three quarters of the way down this page](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html) as a quick reference of what re-ordering are possible on what architectures. It indicates that a StoreStore barrier is a no-op on SPARC, x86 and PA-RISC, but a barrier _is_ needed on PPC, ARM, Itanium and Alpha. Store buffers would seem to make preventing store-store reordering easy at first glance, but it can still happen if the cache lines are "acquired" for write out of order.

Comment: @BeeOnRope, this only deals with intra-thread reordering. These fences are nops on some architectures because you enforce store ordering by default for normal memory types. What we mentioned above is that it does not guarantee consistency of store order (i.e. stores will be observed in different order by different threads). For example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42853642/2016408

Comment: @Leeor - my point is the "store buffering effect" that you get on TSO that requires a `StoreLoad` barrier isn't the the only thing: even if stores are retired "in order" from the point of the view of the CPU, _and_ loads on the reading threads aren't reordered (i.e., put whatever strong barriers you want on the read side), you can still see stores from CPU A out of order with CPU B on some architectures. E.g., `T1` does two stores `[x] = 1; [y] = 1` and `T2` does two reads `y' = [y]; barrier; x' = [x]` you could see `x' ==0 and y' == 1` on `T2`. Note that store buffering ...

Comment: ... or store forwarding doesn't directly come into play here since no thread is reading its own stores, and in fact there is no thread that does both stores and loads. I guess my point is the question of whether stores _execute_ or _retire_ in order locally doesn't tell you much about how the stores are made visible externally, and store buffering isn't the only deviation from sequential consistency: the cache lines may be acquired out of order too. At least on PPC `lwsync` is not a no-op, so basically I am agreeing with @PeterCordes that `StoreStore` may be necessary on some hardware.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: We all agree that these fences/barriers are sometime necessary on some architectures, otherwise they wouldn't exist. However, your example could only occur on very relaxed architectures. x86 for example would enforce store order to be observed identically (the TSO vs. SC difference is only possible when forwarding internal stores). Either way, memory ordering rules don't mention the notion of retirement or execution, they don't require any knowledge of microarchitecture. They apply on the order of operations *as it is perceived externally*.

Comment: @Leeor - I'm pretty sure we agree. My only point was that probably **StoreStore** specifically is not a no-op on all archs (indeed, it might still be a no-op internally for most memory types even if the instruction existed - see `LFENCE` on x86 for example of a barrier that exists but is apparently free). Definitely agreed it's not needed on x86 or SPARC: these are strongly order archs that don't have much (visible) re-ordering beyond what's implied by a store buffer (even that I guess you could hide but it would very costly).

Answer (score 0):

Out of order retirement of store can help in relaxed consistency models. Consider the case when two threads are executing in parallel, if you retire Store A before Store B (out of order) and thread 2 is waiting on A, it can go ahead without having to wait for B to be written before A.

That said, it is very difficult to reverse, in case Store to B results in exception, therefore I do not think it will be of much use in a general system.

Answer (score 0):

My view would be in the case of write back and write allocate policy, when the store instruction misses, the new value of the byte or word must wait until the data block is fetched from the lower level of memory hierarchy. Thus memory access stall the cache due to the cache miss. When there are no exceptions at all, an out of order retirement of store helps in achieving memory-level parallelism.
( Store B has to wait if it is retired in order and store A misses).
This can achieved even in the case with In-order retirement of stores if we introduce miss status handling registers (MSHR) as a part of cache architecture to free up the cache for new accesses. Such a cache would be a non-blocking cache. MSHR is allocated for a cache miss to keep track of the status of the miss. This is required for software prefetching and relaxed consistency models to gain required benefit in performance.